# Convergence and Constant sequence?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

Suppose that $g:\mathbb R \to $$\mathbb R$ is a contraction. Then $g$ has a unique
fixed point $c$ and that for any number $x_0$, the sequence $x_0 x_1 x_2...$ given by
$x_n = g(x_{n-1})$. converges to the fixed point. In certain situations, the speed of convergence may be faster than a rough estimate based only on the contraction constant would suggest.

To be concrete, suppose the fixed point is zero and the contaction constant
is $1/2$. That is, suppose that that $g:\mathbb R \to $$\mathbb R$ satisfies $g(0) = 0$ and that for all $a,b ∈  $$\mathbb R$, $|g(x)-g(y)|<1/2|x-y|$. Let $x_0$ $= 1$. The sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2...$ converges to $0.$

(i) For what n can you be certain that $|x_n|<10^{-100}$?

(ii) If we assume that $g'(0) = 0$ and $|g''(x)|<1$ the sequence ${x_n}\to\ 0$ faster. With these assumptions, for what n can you be certain that $|x_n|<10^{-100}$?

(iii) If we assume that $g'(0) = 0$ and $|g(0)| = 0$, and $g'''(x)<1$, the sequence ${x_n} \to\ 0$ faster still. With these assumptions, for what $n$ can you be certain that $|x_n| < 100^{-100}$?

I am trying to solve this problem, but I can not seem to get through it. I was reading the "Analysis of Numerical Methods" by Isaacson, but he just assumes that things should be known for a beginner.
Is there anyone who can explain each part of these proofs for me or just give a simple version of each proof with what $n$ could be with the assumptions please? This has been very frustrating because I want to learn this this particular problem, but what I was reading does not help. It will be great if you will help!

Comment: I am really stuck. Can someone please help me with this. I know if I see it I will be able to understand what was done.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for part (i):

If we let $x = x_n$ and $y = 0$, then we see that, for every $n$
$$
\left|x_{n+1}\right| = \left|g(x_n) - g(0)\right| < \frac{1}{2}\left|x_n - 0\right| = \frac{1}{2}\left|x_n\right|
$$

Comment: for part (i) $x_n$ $=$ $g(x_{n-1})$. So if we let $x_n$ $=$ 1 then $g(x_{n-1}) = 0$. right? That part I think I got. How would we go about doing this though for part (i) to show for an n where $|x_n|$ < $10^{-100}$ The numbers I seemed to plug in for the explanation you gave me does not seem to work for me. Any more hints or numbers other than 1-5 so I can try to work this out.

Comment: I am stuck. Is there anyway which you can possibly show me please.

Comment: Since $x_0 = 1$, you'll have $\left|x_1\right| < \frac{1}{2}$. Similarly, $\left|x_2\right| < \frac{1}{2}\left|x_1\right| < \frac{1}{2^2}$. So (by induction) $\left|x_n\right| < \frac{1}{2^n}$. How big does $n$ have to be so that $\frac{1}{2^n} < 10^{-100}$?